# Adding \underline{} shortcut in the vertical bar next to structure window - Texmaker

Tags: texmaker, underline, shortcut

I'm wondering if there is a way to add the \underline{} shortcut in the vertical bar next to structure window in Texmaker:

[image]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you open the structure menu, click on the user icon, you can right click to add a tag. See [section 4.4](https://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION33) of the texmaker user manual.

Comment: Hi @Jojo i did it, but the icon doesn't appear.

Comment: It should appear in the user secion of the structure menu.

Comment: My goal is to put the icon in the vertical bar showed in the above figure.

Comment: I'm afraid this is as close as you can get. Texmaker is open-source. You can of course add another icon to the toolbar yourself